# Java 7 binary literals clarification

Tags: java, java-7

As you know, the binary literal is a new feature that is introduced in Java 7:

```
int x = 0b1011;
System.out.println(x); // prints 11 as expected
```

But, when I tried to get the maximum number from the literal binary I got `-1`!!!

```
int x = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111;
System.out.println(x); // prints -1 !!!
```

---

**Further Details:**

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(0b1111111111111111111111111111111); // 31 bits

/* Both print 2147483647 */

/************************************************************************************/

System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println(0b10000000000000000000000000000000); // 32 bits (increment by 1)

/* Both print -2147483648 */

/************************************************************************************/

// And if you keep increasing the binary literal, its actual value
// will be decreased until you reach the maximum binary literal and
// its actual value will be -1.

System.out.println(0b11111111111111111111111111111111); // 32 bits

/* Prints -1 */
```

As you can see, the actual value of the literal binary (while the increment) jumps over from the maximum value of `int` to the minimum one and then keep decreasing till it reaches -1 which is the maximum value of the literal binary.

Is this a bug? or does it have something to do with signed/unsigned numbers?

Comment: This is how all signed 32-bit numbers work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're using a signed integer. Bit 32 (the "first" one from the left) is the sign bit. It being 1 means it is a negative number, and 0 means positive. Two's complement is then performed to give the value of -1. Read about that here:

http://tfinley.net/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html

Comment: I don't think so, `System.out.println(0b011);` still printing `3`

Comment: @Eng.Fouad - as it should. The sign bit is waaaaay to the left :)

Comment: Yes as I said, bit 32 .. 0b011 is actually the following in 32-bit architecture:
00000000000000000000000000000011

Comment: In a signed integer 0b0.... will be positive, 0b1... will be negative. This is correct.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Because `0b011` doesn't set the ***leftmost*** bit to 1. It sets the rightmost two bits to 1, resulting in a (decimal) 3. The ***leftmost*** bit in a Java `int`, when set, indicates a negative number.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a bug at all: since int is unsigned, all bits to 1 *does* mean -1.

The leftmost bit of a signed integer, in two's complement, is the sign bit. What you see is therefore expected.

Comment: Then why `System.out.println(0b011);` prints `3`?

Comment: Maybe bin10=dec2 and bin1=dec1 -> 1+2=3 // bin=binary & dec=decimal

Answer (score 4):

Indeed this is a signed int so is 0xffff == 0b11111111111111111111111111111111 == -1.

This is not a positive number.

See also Wikipedia [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 2):

Java uses 32 bit signed integers, and the max/min & overflow results you are seeing are valid.

For more information see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Answer (score 2):

Java's [`int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) uses [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) signed integers. This means the ***leftmost*** bit indicates a negative number. So

```
int x = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111;
//        ^--- this bit
```

indicates the number is negative. The fact that all of the other bits are also 1 means that the number is (decimal) -1. See the link for details.